# Safe to spawn a new thread inside request thread in spring

Tags: multithreading, spring, controller, thread-safety

I have a spring controller. The request thread from the controller is passed to the @Service annotated Service class. Now I want to do some background work and the request thread must some how trigger the background thread and continue with it's own work and should not wait for the background thread to complete.

My first question : `is this safe to do this.?`
Second question :  `how to do this.?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this safe

Not really. If you have many concurrent users, you'll spawn a thread for everyone of them, and the high number of threads could bring your server to its knees. The app server uses a pool of threads, precisely to avoid this problem.

> How to do this

I would do this by using the [asynchronous capabilities of Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support). Call a service method annotated with `@Async`, and the service method will be executed by another thread, from a configurable pool.